# Workbench Says: Failed to Connect to MySQL at 127.0.0.1:3306 through SSH tunnel at 34.xxx.xxx.xxx:22 with user root

Tags: mysql, sockets, ubuntu, ssh, workbench

Trying to connect to amazon server database through ssh, but getting error
"Failed to Connect to MySQL at 127.0.0.1:3306 through SSH tunnel at 34.xxx.xxx.xxx:22 with user root". The same setting work on other pc. What goes wrong how to overcome it?
I am working on Ubuntu workbench.

Help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to first figure out if it is a workbench problem or a connection problem. Are you able to connect to the database from the terminal? If that succeeds, you wil see a password prompt. If after entering the correct password, access is denied, the problem can be with the ip that is trying to connect to that remote database. For that you need to **GRANT** access.

`mysql >GRANT ALL ON [DatabaseName].* TO 'root'@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY '[PASSWORD]';`

Once you have tried this, share your findings here.